# Share a CPU between more than one application in Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-resource-governance) on Microsoft Docs clearly shows how to share a single CPU between two code Packages inside an Application.

This is done by using `CpuShares`.

Is there a way to use `CpuShares` between two Applications?

Answer (score 0):

All resource governance in Service Fabric is on the Service level.

The information you reference specifies how the CPU reservation for a service (not application) is divided between multiple code packages within the service.

From the article

> Resource governance is supported in Service Fabric in accordance with the service package. The resources that are assigned to the service package can be further divided between code packages.

The above references this article about the service / application model in Service Fabric: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-model